# .last and .each in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, each

I'm trying to get the last record in a view when a new sub comment is created...my code is the following...

```
<% @subcomment = @comment.subcomments.order("created_at").last %>
<% @subcomment.each do |comment| %>
    this worked!
<% end %>
```

I know that @subcomment has the last record...(i.e. when i use .inspect, it shows the object), but for some reason using .each gives the following error...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<Subcomment:0x007fb14c0e5510>):
```

I need to use .each, since I use this view to show all sub comments in general.  How come .each won't work and what are the alternatives?

Thank you.

In the end...I want something like this:

```
<% if defined? showlast %>
    <% @subcomments = @comment.subcomments.order("created_at").last %>
    <% [@subcomments].each do |subcomment| %>
    <div id="subcomments">
<% else %>
<div id="subcomments">
  <% @subcomments.each do |subcomment| %>
     <<here is a long template of what to do with @subcomments>>
```

i.e. I want the template to iterate if multiple and work for the last item if a parameter :showlast is sent

Comment: you are fetching the last subcomment of the comment. It is one entity, not a list. Can't see the point of trying to iterate over one entity. Could you explain what is it that you want?

Comment: ugh, thats what i was afraid of.  I need something that will iterate, regardless of whether there's one record or multiple.

Comment: If you remove .last it will iterate over one or more results.

Comment: yeah, of course...but I only want the last result...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with the iteration?  We may be able to help :)

Comment: I have a template that i use to display all records.  I want to pass it to also display the last record if I pass it a particular parameter.  I need to use the above, but want a way to show just the last record...

Answer (score 1):

Using last will only bring you one option, you can't iterate over a single thing.

Comment: so is there something I can use that will iterate regardless of whether there's one record or multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you want to enforce an iteration over a single entity, the easiest way is to create an array with one element.

In this case, instead of `@subcomment.each` try using `[@subcomment].each` in your block.

That being said, I would recommend that you relook this approach. Your lookup is doing a `.last`, which assures a single entity being returned. So, you could just use that instead of iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `<<here is a long template of what to do with @subcomments>>` into a partial called `_subcomment.html.erb`. Then you can simply do this:

```
<div id="subcomments">
  <% if defined? showlast %>
    <%= render @comment.subcomments.order("created_at").last %>
  <% else %>
    <% @subcomments.each do |subcomment| %>
      <%= render subcomment %>
    <% end%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```